# Facebook Graph API: How to find object_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to understand how to find the `object_id` of a Facebook post in order to send a GET request to the Facebook Graph API. I'm trying to pull all the comments to this post using this request:

`https://graph.facebook.com/object_id/comments?access_token=XXX`

but I'm not sure how to find the object ID of a post in my page.

Comment: Get the page feed first, and find the post in there? Or combine numeric page id and post id (the latter you can get from the URL, when you are viewing the post on its own) with an underscore in the middle.

Comment: @misorude what do you from the URL when I view the post? I'm viewing the post on the feed, there is no place to click it

Comment: The date link under the poster name / page name links to the individual post view …